# Generic type vs wildcard compile issue in java

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, wildcard

I am facing a generic vs wildcard issue in java.

```
class A<T> {
    T value;
}

class B<T> {
    T value;
}

public <T> A<? extends B<T>> methodA() {

    A<B<Object>> gg = fetchFromSomeLocation();
    return (A<? extends B<T>>) gg;
}

public <T, E extends B<T>> A<E> methodB() {

    A<B<Object>> gg = fetchFromSomeLocation();
    return (A<E>) gg;
}
```

So methodB() compiles fine, no issue. But methodA causes compilation to fail with:

```
incompatible types: A<B<java.lang.Object>> cannot be converted to A<? extends B<T>>
```

I am not able to understand why this is so.

P.S on Intellij it shows as fine valid code.

EDIT

so apparently this compiles just fine

```
public static <T> A<? extends B<T>> methodC() {

    A<B<Object>> gg = new A<>();
    return (A<? extends B<T>>)(A<?>) gg;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `return new A<>();`?

Comment: @shmosel see edit :) actually this is just some sample code. in the original problem i can not return new A<>()

Comment: Then how about `return (A<? extends B<T>>)(A<?>) gg;`?

Comment: woah. this compiled just fine. but why is this so !?